# How to extract nested JSON objects in presto?

Tags: json, presto

Can someone please help explain how to extract this nested JSON objects in Presto? Here is what I have in a column called 'data':

I tried this code but it returns None :(

{"RESPONSE":"NEW","NEXT":"STEP1","RULE":"{"TYPE1":"false","TYPE2":"true","TYPE3":"false"}"}

> SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.RULE.TYPE1') AS type1
>   , JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.RULE.TYPE2') AS type2
>   , JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.RULE.TYPE3') AS type3
>   FROM table

Answer (score 0):

The query is right, but the JSON data has extra double quotations in front and end of the nested object.

If you fix the data like this, it will return the right response.

```
{"RESPONSE":"NEW","NEXT":"STEP1","RULE":{"TYPE1":"false","TYPE2":"true","TYPE3":"false"}}
```

Comment: thanks for answering! But how do I efficiently remove the double quotation marks you mentioned? I have thousands of rows like this. Please advice!

Comment: As the workaround, you can use replace function. select replace(replace('<wrong-json>', ':"{"', ':{"'), '"}"', '"}'). This may break the other characters, though.